# How to test a helper functions used in controller in Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I am using sinon.js to test my API. 
I would like to test the order from my helper functions that are being called.

**controller.js**

```
exports.controllerFunction = async (req, res) => { 

    const function1Results = await function1(paramm);

    const function2Results = await function2(param, function1Results);

    return res.send(function2Results);
};
```

**helpers.js**

```
exports.function1 = function(param) {
 return param;
}

exports.function2 = function(param, func) {
 return param;
}
```

**unitTest.js**

```
const controller = require('./controller.js')
const helpers = require('./helpers.js')

describe('Unit test cycle', () => {
 beforeEach(() => {
  // Spies
  sinon.spy(controller, 'controllerFunction');
  sinon.spy(helpers, 'function1');
  sinon.spy(helpers, 'function2');

  // Function calls
  controller.controllerFunction(this.req, this.res)
 })

 afterEach(() => {
  sinon.restore();
 })

 this.req = {}
 this.res = {}

 it('should call getAvailability', (done) => {
  expect(controller.controllerFunction.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(helpers.function1.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(helpers.function2.calledOnce).to.be.true
 });
})
```

```
expect(controller.controllerFunction.calledOnce).to.be.true
```

is returning in as **true**

```
  expect(helpers.function1.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(helpers.function2.calledOnce).to.be.true
```

and is coming in as **false**.

Because my helper functions are being used in the controller they should be called as well, yet they are not.

So how do I test if my helper functions are being called as well when the controller is tested?

Comment: Did you try to set spies on those functions?

Comment: Yes I did, I will edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a shot. Since your function is `async` I think your block for testing should be made to `await` for it.

I recommend moving the function call inside the `it` block of commands. `beforeEach` is usually used for setup, `afterEach` is used to clear some data/mocks (also known as tear).

Try

```
it('should call getAvailability', async (done) => {
  // When
  await controller.controllerFunction(this.req, this.res)
  // Assert
  expect(controller.controllerFunction.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(helpers.function1.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(helpers.function2.calledOnce).to.be.true
  done && done()
 });
```

Don't forget to remove the function call from beforeEach.

Comment: Nice try. This was the error I got: understood that it now throws an exception Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback * or * return a Promise; not both.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but that didn't do it.